# How have a row change color from data in a cell

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that I am making and I am having trouble with a format. I have columns from A-Q and cells from 4-100, what I want to be able to do is the last column (Q) is for invoice #'s so I want to be able to when someone enters an invoice number the whole row changes color, is that possible?

Comment: You want the color change based on what condition? As in if a value is entered then color change or if a specific value is entered then have a specific color?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a conditional format with the custom formula

```
=NOT(ISBLANK($Q2))
```

In the "Format" menu, select "Conditional formatting...", then apply the pictured settings.

[image]